# Using AngularJS, how do I pass a controllers scope to a directives html template

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm having trouble accessing variables in my controllers scope inside a directives html template. I'm unsure how I should be passing it's scope to my html for display because I plan to use multiple copies of this same directive.

Currently no matter even if I remove the controller from the project, the value of the expression's in compound.html displays  "0".

How do I pass the controller "compoundController" to "compound.html" directive template?

**Index**

```
<compound objectid="{{controll.compoundId}}"></compound>
```

**Directive**

```
angular.module('ireg').directive('compound', function () {
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope: {             
            objectid:'@objectid'
        },
        controller: 'compoundController',
        templateUrl: 'compound.html'
    }
});
```

**Controller**

```
angular.module('ireg').controller("compoundController",
  ['$scope','$routeParams','compoundService', 
  function($scope,$attrs,compoundService ){
    var vm = this;
    vm.objectid = 2;
    vm.compoundData;

    vm.getPayload = function(scope, compoundController){
        var promise = compoundService.getData($scope.objectid);
        promise.then(
            function(payload) { 
                vm.compoundData = payload.data[0];
            }
        );
    };

}]);
```

**Service**

```
angular.module('ireg').factory('compoundService', function($http) {
    return {
        getData: function(id) {
            var url = "http://localhost:8080/return-compound-data.php?compound=" +id;
            return $http.get(url);
        }
    }
});
```

**Compound.html**

```
    <div class = "panel-heading">
        <div class="card-title"> {{compound-controller.compound-data.project_name}} </div>
    </div>  <!-- end of panel heading -->

    <div class = "panel-body" >
        <table class = "rwd-table">
            <tr>
                <th>Compound Number</th>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td data-th="Compound Number">{{controll.compound_number}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the '='operator in the directive fore the scope mapping and leave the curly brackets in the html tag away.

```
<compound objectid="controll.compoundId"></compound>

 scope: {             
        objectid:'=objectid'
    },
```

EDIT: At second sight there are plenty of bugs in your code. I didn't really understand how your code is supposed to work, but I made a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Phj3e1Bfi1bzug6770pM?p=preview). Hope this helps